# Cannot Find .NET 4.0 Uninstaller after Visual Studio 2012 Installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, inno-setup

I'm trying to create an Inno Setup script to install .net framework 4.0 as prerequisite .My application requires .net 4.0 Full,so im checking the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4`.Im testing this on the deployment machine,so i thought about uninstalling .net 4.0 Full which i had installed,but when i check for the uninstaller i cannot find 4.0 uninstaller

[image]

I had installed Visual Studio 2012 and i think it replaced the .NET 4.0 with 4.5.The problem is that i cannot find .NET 4.0 Uninstaller.Here are my doubts

1.Does installing .NET 4.5 add 4.0 Registry entries  in addition to 4.5

2.Has Visual Studio Installation Replaced my existing .NET 4.0 Installation?

Comment: From what I know 4.5 replaces 4.0 _in place_, so I am not that surprised you don't find traces of 4.0

Comment: Clearly you didn't actually install 4.0 so removing it is not correct.  Just never do this.  Once you've installed the .NET Framework on a machine you've lost control over its usage.  There will be other installers that rely on your kindness to get the job done for them, they'll skip installing it themselves.  You'll break every app that relied on that.  The .NET Framework is an integral part of Windows these days, not in the least because it has come pre-installed on Windows for many years now.  If the user wants to uninstall it then that's their prerogative, never help.

Comment: @HansPassant I actually installed it and i can see the registry entries for it(4.0 full)

Comment: @flq does it mean that the uninstaller for 4.0 is removed?

Comment: Having 4.5 installed also means that any program that targets 4.0 is going to be happy.  So sure, you'll see keys that mention 4.0.  Stay away from undocumented private keys that .NET uses for its own house-keeping.

Comment: You need to test your prerequisite check and install on a fresh VM (preferably one that supports snapshots and rollback so that you can test it repeatedly).  It's too late to test it on your development machine, because .NET 4.5 supercedes .NET 4.0.

Comment: @techno that would be the conclusion, yes.